# How to open paths from terminal to PhpStorm on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, phpstorm

I write on the react, sometimes errors and warnings arrive in the terminal, as well as ways to them. I know you can switch to VS Code by holding command, but how to do it in PhpStorm on a mac?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No way; please vote for [WEB-50400](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50400) to be notified on any progress with it

You can try the [Awesome Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7677-awesome-console) plugin - see if it makes things any better